# How do you associate DOM elements with tween.js?

Tags: tween.js

How do you relate `TWEEN.js` to a DOM element to do some complicated (or simple) animation effects on this DOM element?

I got a demo on the Internet, you need to create a sophisticated animation (using three.js) and DOM (to show or hide the elements associated with a TWEEN.js to DOM elements, DOM elements) has been written in the inside of the HTML (just slow to show or hide the effect).

The implementation of the clickMeOk method has achieved animation effects, but I hope to perform another effect at the same time - the display or hiding of text descriptions (shown or hidden with animation)

```
var isMeTweening = false;
function clickMeOk() {
    if (isMeTweening) 
        return;
    isMeTweening = true;
    var scale = mesh6.scale.x < 1 ? 1 : 0.001;

    new TWEEN.Tween(mesh6.scale)
        .to({ x: scale, y: scale, z: scale }, 2000)
        .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quartic.InOut)
        .onComplete(function() {
            isMeTweening = false;
        }).start();

    var opacity = mesh6.material.opacity > 0 ? 0 : 0.5;
    new TWEEN.Tween(mesh6.material).to({ opacity: opacity }, 1800).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quartic.InOut).start();

    //Here you want to add DOM element animation (display or hide)




}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You should use CSS to make animations on DOM Elements.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp